# Can't anchor idl init

Tags: anchor-program-idl, idl

when I try to anchor IDL init, i get stuck permanently trying to finalize the txn.

```
anchor idl init --filepath ./target/idl/solotesting2.json Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS --provider.cluster devnet
⠉ [0/32] Finalizing transaction 5QtxFFkTaQ17Lb3NMx9VCqoEbwk593VZcL3RvvB6gnEeaWoC
```

then it gives me

```
Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds

Caused by:
    unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug in 1.11.5, which I believe was introduced as part of the QUIC rollout, please use 1.11.4 instead.

Comment: still getting the same error with a version switch